# Referencing files from the working directory java

Tags: java, file

My jar and a folder are in the directory C:\path\to\dir. This folder is called "server" and its path is C:\path\to\dir\server. The file layout looks like this:

- C:\path\to\dir

  - myJarFile.jar
  - server

    - server.properties

I want to make a buffered reader for the server.properties file, read it, then delete it. How would I accomplish this? Also, the jar file will always be launched from the folder it is in.

Comment: What have you tried so far? How far did you get before hitting problems? Where's the code so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
File file  = new File("server/server.properties");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
...
file.delete();
```